# Definir metodo doPost , duda con el metodo action

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

Como puedo realizar un metodo doPost correctamente, quiero declarar una peticion ajax para devolver un nombre, una suma y un producto con servlets, me aparece un error a a la hora de declarar el else, mis archivos son

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo Ajax</title>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/miPrimerCSS.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#unHola').click(function(){
         var nombreCompleto = $('#nombreCompleto').val();
         $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             data: {
                 nombreCompleto : nombreCompleto,
                 action: 'demo1'
             },
             url: 'AjaxController',
             success: function(result){
                 $('#resultadoNombre').html(result);
             }

         });
     });

     $('#unaSuma').click(function(){
         var numero1 = $('#numero1').val();
         var numero2 = $('#numero2').val();
         $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             data: {
                 numero1 : numero1,
                 numero2 : numero2,  
                 action: 'demo2'
             },
             url:'AjaxController',
             success : function(result){
                 $('#resultadoSuma').html(result);
             }

         });
     });

     $('#unProducto').click(function(){
         var numero1 = $('#numa').val();
         var numero2 = $('#numb').val();
         $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             data: {
                 numa : numa,
                 numb : numb,  
                 action: 'demo3'
             },
             url:'AjaxController',
             success : function(result){
                 $('#resultadoProd').html(result);
             }

         });
     });
 }); 

</script>
</head>

 <body>



<nav>


  <div class="nav-wrapper">

    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">  Logo</a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="sass.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Pages</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Lab</a></li>
      <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
      <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li> -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>






     <div class="container">
      <p class="z-depth-5">
     <fieldset>
        <h3>Un Hola</h3>
           <form>
              Introduce tu nombre <input type="text" id="nombreCompleto"><br>
              <input type="button" value="Hola" id="unHola"><br> 
              <span id="resultadoNombre"></span>
           </form>
     </fieldset>
     </div>

     <br><br>


    <div class="container">
    <fieldset>
        <h3>Una Suma</h3>
        <form>
            Numero 1 <input type="text" id="numero1"><br> 
            Numero 2 <input type="text" id="numero2"><br> 
            Resultado <span
                id=resultadoSuma></span><br> <input type="button" value="Suma"
                id="unaSuma">
        </form>  
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <fieldset>
        <h3>Un Producto</h3>
        <form>
            Numero 1 <input type="text" id="numero1"><br> 
            Numero 2 <input type="text" id="numero2"><br> 
            Resultado <span id=resultadoProd></span><br> <input type="button" value="Producto"
                id="unProducto">
        </form>  
        </fieldset>
    </div>







        <footer class="page-footer">
          <div class="container">
            <h5 class="white-text">Footer Content</h5>

              </div>


          <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">
            © 2014 Copyright Text
            <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>  
  </body>

</html>
```

y un controlador ajax

**AjaxController.java**

```
package controladores;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AjaxController
 */
@WebServlet("/AjaxController")
public class AjaxController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AjaxController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain ");

        PrintWriter out =  response.getWriter();
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if(action.equals("demo1")){
            String nombreCompleto = request.getParameter("nombreCompleto");
            out.println("Hola " + nombreCompleto);
        }
        else if (action.equals("demo2")){
            int a = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero1"));
            int b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero2"));
            out.println(a + b);
        } else (action.equals("demo3")){
            int d = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numa"));
            int c = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numb"));
            out.print(c * d);
        }



    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: +]

Comment: Aquí falta algo... `} else (action.equals("demo3")){`

Comment: Para poner una condicion en un else debes poner else if.

Comment: la manera de corregirlo fue haber colocado un if else nuevamente y de esa manera se arreglo el problema, aun así gracias por la información.